# Is there any non-human organic life still alive by the time of the events of 'The Matrix'?

Tags: the-matrix

We are told in *The Matrix* by Morpheus that humanity had blocked sunlight in the hope that it would prevent the Machines from recharging.  At the same time though, almost all life depends on sunlight, either directly or indirectly.  Therefore, by blocking sunlight, it would severely hinder the capability of organisms to survive.

My question is then, **by the time of the events of *The Matrix* when Neo is freed from The Matrix, is there any non-human organic life?**

Comment: @Richard Surely a dupe of a good question is also good and therefore deserves upvotes? (leaving aside e.g. writing quality, which isn't an issue here)

Comment: @randal'thor - I didn't downvote. Just pointing out that that's why someone might have downvoted it.

Comment: @N_Soong While the question itself differs slightly, I think Richard is calling it a dupe because the accepted answer there pretty well covers this question. (As I understand, a question qualifies as a dupe if the questions are related and the answer is covered.)

Comment: @jpmc26 cc Richard - my mistake; I didn't see the reference to the animal outside of the Matrix.  Yes, that is correct, a question is a dupe if it asks a question already answered by another's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes

*The Miller's Tale* (archived link [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20040614034230/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/rl_cmp/paulcMiller1a.html)) includes pictures of plants, fungi, and even a few small animals:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The events of the comic took place when Morpheus was a boy. Since these life forms survived the [Machine War](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Machine_War) and [Operation Dark Storm](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Operation_Dark_Storm) (which scorched the skies), these life forms were very likely still alive during the events of *The Matrix* when Morpheus was an adult.

Comment: I'm awarding this the correct answer, because it actually refers to naturally occurring animals that are living within nature rather than suspended in a tube which is more in line with the spirit of the question

Answer (score 7):

The only one I can recall is that in [Matriculated](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Matriculated) (the last part of the Animatrix) for some reason the rebels are in possession of a few yellow-green cylinders with some kind of small monkey suspended in them ([tarsiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarsier) is my best guess). They do move around, which I assume means they're still alive.

[image]

Comment: Great find!  You have my +1 :)

Comment: @N_Soong Now if only someone could tell us *why* the rebels were running around with these monkeys suspended in tubes.